# k3s HA cluster and secrets encryption

Tags: k3s

My first steps with kubernetes. I built a "HA cluster" with k3s (like described here: https://docs.k3s.io/datastore/ha-embedded). My 3 nodes are running and I want to encrypt secrets from beginning.

I followed description in https://docs.k3s.io/cli/secrets-encrypt#secrets-encryption-disablere-enable

- Enabled secrets encryption on a node with `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s - server --secrets-encryption` (source: https://docs.k3s.io/security/secrets-encryption)
- Encryption status is enabled (with `k3s secrets-encrypt status`)
- Restart k3 service on this node
- After enabled encryption my 2 other nodes don't start anymore (hang up). If I disable encryption on node, all nodes will start again as before

My questions:

- How can I setup a k3s cluster with secrets encryption?
- How can I add new k3s nodes when secrets encryption is enabled?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after several tries:

1. Init k3s cluster `NODE-1`

```bash
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_TOKEN=<YOUR-CLUSTER-TOKEN> sh -s - server --cluster-init --secrets-encryption
```

2. Check `NODE-1` secrets encryption status with

```bash
k3s secrets-encrypt status
# Encryption Status: Enabled
```

3. Check `NODE-1` cluster flags with (important: cluster-init, secrets-encryption)

```bash
nano /etc/systemd/system/k3s.service
# ...
# ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/k3s \
#    server \
#        '--cluster-init' \
#        '--secrets-encryption' \
```

4. Join next k3s Server Node `NODE-2`: Run on `NODE-2`

```bash
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_TOKEN=<YOUR-CLUSTER-TOKEN> sh -s - server --secrets-encryption --server <NODE-1-IP>:6443
```

- same flags as `NODE-1` (without cluster-init)
- in docs (https://docs.k3s.io/datastore/ha-embedded) I left https in `--server <NODE-1-IP>:6443`. Join doesn't work with https for me.

5. Check `NODE-2` secrets encryption status with

```bash
k3s secrets-encrypt status
# Encryption Status: Enabled
```

6. List all k3s cluster nodes

```bash
sudo k3s kubectl get nodes
# NAME     STATUS   ROLES                       AGE   VERSION
# NODE-1   Ready    control-plane,etcd,master   46h   v1.28.8+k3s1
# NODE-2   Ready    control-plane,etcd,master   45h   v1.28.8+k3s1
```